# How to change .p12 password?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, keytool

I have a .p12 file and I need to change its password.
And this new password have to be "1234"

I already tried to do this with Keytool :

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore authentification.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass "2600807934-Auth" -destkeystore new.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -storepass 1234
```

But i got an error message telling me that the new password must contains at lesat 6 char.

Do you no another way to do this ?
(I got other .p12 files with "1234" as password, so it is possible)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with two subsequent [`openssl pkcs12`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/pkcs12.html) commands. First, to extract your contents from the `.p12` file, use

```
openssl pkcs12 -in contents.p12 -out contents.txt
```

It will ask you for the password to access `contents.p12` (1234 in your case), as well as a new password for encrypting the private key that ends up in `contents.txt` (and an additional time to verify you did not make a typo).

The you can use the following command to re-construct a `.p12` from `contents.txt`:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in contents.txt -out contents_new.p12
```

It will ask you for the password that you used to encrypt the private key in the previous step, as well as a new password for the `.p12` bundle (and again an additional time to verify you did not make a typo).

Comment: Can we ignore the first password (*"for encrypting the private key that ends up in `contents.txt`"*) and leave it empty? Isn't the second password (*"for the `.p12` bundle"*) enough? In the above process, it seems the first password is useless (we open and remove it in the second step)! Not?